# OpenCL possible reason a clGetEventInfo would cause a segfault?

Tags: events, opencl

I have a pretty complicated OpenCL app. It fires up 5 different contexts on 5 different GPUs, and executes the same kernel on all of them, splitting up the work into 1024 "chunks" to be processed.

Each time a kernel finishes, a result is checked for, and it's given a new chunk. Sometimes, when running, as the app is starting (very rarely mid-run) it will immediately segfault on the GetEventInfo call.

This is done in a loop using callbacks and clGetEventInfo calls to ensure something is finished before moving on to the next step.

GDB output:

```
(gdb) back
#0  0x00007fdc686ab525 in clGetEventInfo () from /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1
#1  0x00000000004018c1 in ready (event=0x26a00000267) at gputest.c:165
#2  0x0000000000404b5a in main (argc=9, argv=0x7fffdfe3b268) at gputest.c:544
```

The ready function:

```
int ready(cl_event event) {
  int rdy;

  if(!event)
    return 0;

  clGetEventInfo(event, CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS, sizeof(cl_int), &rdy, NULL);

  if(rdy == CL_COMPLETE)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

How the kernel is run, the event set, and checked. Some pseudocode inserted for brevity:

```
while(test if loop is complete) {
  for(j = 0; j < GPUS; j++) {
    if(gpu[j].waiting && loops < 9999) {
      gpu[j].waiting = 0;
      offset[j] = loops * 1024 * 1024;
      loops++;
      EC("kernel init", clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queues[j], kernel_init[j], 1, &(offset[j]), &global_work_size, &work128, 0, NULL, &events[j]));
      gpu[j].readsearch = events[j];
      gpu[j].reading = 1;
    }
  }

  for(j = 0; j < GPUS; j++) {
    if(gpu[j].reading && ready(gpu[j].readsearch)) {
      gpu[j].reading = 0;
      gpu[j].waiting = 1;
    // unrelated reporting other code here
    }
  }
}
```

Its pretty simple. There is more to the code, but it's unrelated. The ready/checking function is very simple. I even added debugging to the ready function to printf the event # to see what was happening when it crashed - nothing really. No pattern I could see.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I can't see any reason why the code you have posted should fail. Have you tried adding a small delay into the loop? maybe 0.1 seconds. ideally, less than the average kernel execution time if possible.

Comment: Sorry, yes, there is a usleep(1000) at the end of the loop. I'm also having crashes where the GDB output is complaining about start_thread at pthread_create.c and crashes in ?? from /usr/lib/libamdocl64.so - its starting to drive me nuts that I cannot find the issue.

Comment: Oh now this is new. Instead of a segfault there, I just got this: *** Error in `./gputest': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000011d4100 *** - I'm not even freeing anything at that point.

Comment: would it be non-trivial to try a much smaller work size? maybe 32x32 instead of 1024x1024? what about when you try only a single gpu or different combinations of gpus, does it still crash?

Comment: I cannot change the work group size, the kernel is hard coded to a specific size (and the workgroup size was chosen specifically to fit the work being done). I changed it to use just 1 GPU, and it still crashes (I was about to type that it does not, but ran it again, and it crashed)

Comment: Pretty sure I found the issue for the double free/corruption, but it was in an area of code that had nothing to do with the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Found the problem. Since you cannot initialize values when you create/declare a struct, I was using some values uninitialized. I malloc'ed the gpu structs then just started using them. With if(gpu[x].reading &&...) being random data and completely uninitialized. So sometimes it was non-zero, which allowed the ready() function to fire off. Since the gpu[x].readsearch event was never set in the first place, clGetEventInfo bombed trying to use whatever was at the memory location.

This would be time number 482,847 that accidentally using uninitialized variables has burned me.